# Batch file - Add a log file for every .exe executed

Tags: batch-file

```
 for /r %%f in (*.exe) do (start /wait %%f /quiet /norestart @echo "Done" >> E:\WindowsUpdate\Alog.txt)
```

I want to create a log file for every file that is executed to check its properties with the code above. These files are vcredist (Microsoft Visual c++ updates). But it only creates the log file and writes nothing. Any help will do.

Comment: You are aware that the outputs of any executable are determined by the developer of that executable aren't you? I'm also unsure whether you know that there is no way of being sure if that executables' output is console or GUI based. For that reason it is impossible for us to provide you with a response that can be used with any degree of certainty.

Comment: Actually these exe files are vcredist (Microsoft Visual c++ updates). I heard that you can add a command where you will let it check a check box even if its in quiet mode.

Comment: All pertinent information should be in you question, not added bit by bit if and when sombody raises a comment. The better your question the greater the possibility of receiving useful responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those executables should use `msiexec.exe` which has a standard option for logging information.

```dos
`… /quiet /norestart /log E:\WindowsUpdate\Alog.txt`
```

If this is not what you mean then please update your question with more information because your question talks about logging information and your comment checking a check box.

Comment: Like if the update is already installed and there is a feature in the update that repair the current installation. Is it lawful to add /repair or modify? for example,
`/quiet /repair /norestart /log E:\WindowsUpdate\Alog.txt`
I found in the log file that there is this string "Current Operation value is Repairing"